# Do the atomic model animations between scenes have any meaning in The Big Bang Theory?

Tags: the-big-bang-theory

In The Big Bang Theory there are these atomic model animations between changing of scenes. There are many combinations of them. Am listing few below.

[image: String of atomis.]

[image: Single atom.]

[image: Two atoms.]

Do these in-between animations have any significance? Like they might be indication of characters or any hidden themes?

Comment: I'm curious if you found the answer you desired. I was particularly interested in the colours of the animation backgrounds. I've started making a spreadsheet to analyse, which is based on background colours, scene emotions, and the corresponding lines to each transition. I would continue only if you haven't got your answer.

Comment: @niamulbengali: Sure. Please continue. I haven't yet accepted an answer. I might also award a bounty if there is detailed answer.

Answer (score 7):

I have noticed a general correlation between the number of atoms in the animation and the number of characters (or main characters) in the following scene.

I've also noticed that in some cases, the actions of the atoms in the animations may foreshadow something about the following scene. For example, if there are two atoms that move apart and then collide, the following scene may center on two characters who separate from each other and then come together for a passionate kiss.

Comment: Can you support your answer with some occurrences ?

Comment: [The video linked here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlKtsUd0cEI) starts with 4 parts of the atom, and there are 4 people in it. And [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPHnvEX2T1o) starts with 3 atoms, and is followed by a scene with 3 people.

Comment: I do remember once a quarrel was about to happen between two persons and the atom scene was that two atoms collide. Can't remember which part was it though.

Comment: True or not but your observation is indeed interesting..

Answer (score 0):

I've read that the colors the characters are wearing, specifically Sheldon, indicate their emotions or perhaps give hints to the scene. Such as a character wearing red, he might argue or get in a fight.

It's also possible that the animations use similar color schemes and movement patterns to indicate the scenes as well.

https://www.looper.com/7496/hidden-things-missed-big-bang-theory/
https://www.8ball.co.uk/blogs/8ball/what-do-sheldon-cooper-s-t-shirts-mean

Comment: Is that specific to TBBT? If so, could you please [edit] in a source? This looks a bit too general right now, but if clarify whether that was made on purpose for this show, it would make for a better answer.

Comment: what do you mean specific to big bang.. as opposed to other tv shows or.?? I added a couple links.. if you google it, itll pop uo with several websites discussing the colors

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant. As per the googling part - answers on Stack Exchange site's should be self-contained and not require further googling by the reader to understand/check the info. Your answer is a better one now that you've addressed that point.

Comment: I just put links up.. so whether you google or not shouldnt matter because i put the links up. Also the highest rated answer on most boards dont contain links i think youre being picky.  also i thought it was common sense that I wasnt referring to every single tv show ever made in the history of mankind using colors to represent emotion since we are talking on a post about big bang..

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it requires such a deep understanding regarding the atom sequence. It's a scientific show and the atomic sequence just suggests that, just like the electron's position and velocity can't be ascertained at the same time according to the Heisenberg Uncertainty principle, the same way the plot line is very unpredictable.

For example, even though we knew that Leonard and Penny would get hitched, the way the story went, there were still moments where it didn't seem so or suggested that it might not happen.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that this is the case, that you could [edit] in?